# CSS animation delay from # of children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a java script that offsets the start and loop delays  of CSS animations. the offset should be based off of the number of images in the containing div.
I'm not very experienced with javascript so any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript:

```
function bannersImgOffset(){

var photoBanners = document.getElementsByClassName("photoBanner");
for(var i=0; i < photoBanners.length; i++){

    var bannerChildren = i.getChildNodes;
    var loopDelay = bannerChildren.length*5;

    for(i=0, i>bannerChildren.length, i++){
        var imageDelay = (i*5); 

        i.style.webkitanimation = "bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s";
        i.style.mozanimation = "bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s";
        i.style.msanimation = "bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s";
        i.style.oanimation = "bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s";
        i.style.animation = "bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s";

        i.style.webkitanimationDelay = imageDelay + "s";
        i.style.mozanimationDelay = imageDelay + "s";
        i.style.msanimationDelay = imageDelay + "s";
        i.style.oanimationDelay = imageDelay + "s";
        i.style.animationDelay = imageDelay + "s";
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="photoBanner">
        <img src="Image01.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Image02.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Image03.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Image04.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Image05.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of your code? And what is the expected result?

Comment: For goodness sakes, collapse the 5 copes of `"bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s"` down to one and the 5 copies of `imageDelay + "s"` down to one.  Then, read the principles of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself).

Comment: java !== javascript ;)

Comment: I see now the first 5 copies of <code>"bannerCycle 5s linear infinite " + loopDelay + "s"</code> are redundant and have removed them. But I can't collapse down the 5 iterations of <code>'image Delay + "s"<code> unless I can detect the browser first which seems like it would get heavy.

it appears <code>i.getChildNodes;<code> is returning as undefined. is that a valid command?

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to use the same variable to set your second level for loop? If not, try using a different variable inside the 2nd level for loop.